# Why I get empty form? How to automatically create Iniline models?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

There are `2 forms` on one page.

There are 2 models: 1. `Product`. 2. `SpeciallyPrice`. `SpeciallyPrice` is linked via **FK** to `Product`. At the same time, `SpeciallyPrice` is **Inline**  model  in `Product`.

The fields of the `SpecialPriceForm` are automatically created using **JS**. That is, them may be the **n**-th number. It is necessary to create a record for each created field. In principle, I guess how to do it - use the cycle to drive the values obtained. But the problem is that for some reason **None** comes from the `form`. Please help me.

```
class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(ProductsCreate, self).get_initial()
        initial['request'] = self.request

        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx=super(ProductsCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['special_form'] = SpeciallyPriceForm()
        return ctx

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        if kwargs.get('slug'):
            category = Category.objects.filter(slug=kwargs.get('slug')).first()
            self.initial.update({'category': category})
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = ProductCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'request': request})
        special_form = SpeciallyPriceForm(request.POST)
        print(special_form)           #Template of form, without values.
        if form.is_valid() and special_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, special_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, special_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, special_form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.user = self.request.user
        product.save()

        special = special_form.save(commit=False)
        #Here I think, depending on the number of list items, to cycle through it and create the corresponding number of `special` records associated with this` product`. Is the logic correct?
        special.product = product
        special.save()

        for spec_price in special_form.cleaned_data.get('adittional_specially_price'):
            print(spec_price)
            special.adittional_specially_price = spec_price
        for spec_numb in special_form.cleaned_data.get('adittional_specially_number'):
            print(spec_numb)
            special.adittional_specially_number = spec_numb
```

**forms**

```
class SpeciallyPriceForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = SpeciallyPrice 
        fields = ['adittional_specially_price', 'adittional_specially_number']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SpeciallyPriceForm, self).clean()
        cd_adittional_specially_price = cleaned_data.get('adittional_specially_price')
        print(cd_adittional_specially_price)   #None
        cd_adittional_specially_number = cleaned_data.get('adittional_specially_number')
        print(cd_adittional_specially_number)  #None
```

**template + js**

```
<html><body>
Special price from {{ special_form.adittional_specially_price }} kg {{ special_form.adittional_specially_number }} usd

    <script>
        (function(){
            var copy = document.querySelector('.field.inline.specially').cloneNode(true);
            document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('input', function(e){
                if(e.target.classList.contains('event') && e.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                    var error = 0;
                    for(var evt of document.querySelectorAll('.field.inline.specially input.event')){
                        evt.value = evt.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'');
                        if(!evt.value || +evt.value < 1) error++;
                    }
                    if(!error){
                        var last = document.querySelectorAll('.field.inline.specially');
                        last[last.length-1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', copy.outerHTML);
                    }
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body></html>
```

This form i get in views, when print `form` for checking

```
<label for="specially" class="subhead">Special price from</label>
<span class="id_specially_price"><input type="text" name="adittional_specially_price" style="width: 165px" class="event" id="id_adittional_specially_price"></span>
<span>kg</span>
<span class="id_specially_number"><input type="text" name="adittional_specially_number" style="width: 100px" class="event" id="id_adittional_specially_number"></span>
<span>usd</span>
```

I looked in the **views** - the form is rendered there, but only with *one* field, and not with everything. And the *form is empty* .. How to solve this issue? Maybe *Ajax* should be connected and it somehow process the request? Or is there a more *Django's* option?

Comment: I think you want to use an `inlineformset_factory` with the JS Django provides.  Try this tutorial (https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d) which is a good starting point.

Comment: @HenryM Thank. It seems easy. Just do not quite understand it "with the JS Django provides". Perhaps, for this I will need to create a new question, if I do not understand? Or I will be able to contact you somehow?

Comment: @HenryM this does not work(

Comment: @HenryM This may be due to the fact that the new fields added using JS have the same ID. And when I look at the form in views, it shows me the last two fields that are left empty when sending a request?

Comment: @HenryM Yes, that's exactly it. I solved the problem with ID. And really come the last two empty created with JS fields. How to make all fields come, tell me, please?

Comment: You should use a regular view instead of a class-based view. And then use inlineformset_factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this bit of comments: "And really come the last two empty created with JS fields. How to make all fields come, tell me, please?"

To save an inline formset in a CBV:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    inline_form = context['inline_form']
    if inline_form.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save()
        inline_form.instance = self.object
        inline_form.save()
```

Clearly you'll have to use the right name for `inline_form` within the `context`.